# Set thread number or thread group id for properties in Jmeter

Tags: multithreading, properties, jmeter

How can I set thread name or thread group id for props in jmeter? I want to setup my scenario as below: If I have 6 thread, I will have 6 properties different. And how can call it in configuration?

Answer (score 0):

If you define a JMeter property called `foo` with the value of `bar` in one of the below ways:

1. Add the next line to [*user.properties* file](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#configuring_jmeter):

   ```
   foo=bar
   ```
2. Or pass the property via [`-J` command-line argument](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#override):

   ```
   jmeter -Jfoo=bar -t test.jmx
   ```

You will be able to access its value using [__P() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__P) wherever you want as:

```
${__P(foo)}
```

Demo:

[image]

Check out [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization) to learn more about JMeter Properties and ways of setting/overriding them